# What is the time basis for offset programs?

Tags: carbon-offsetting

I'm kicking around the idea of creating a local offset program. My question is: what is the time basis for offsets? Best seen with an example.

Say I build a solar PV system that costs $10,000 and produces enough electricity to offset a tonne of CO<sub>2</sub>/year for 25 years. If I'm an institution trying to offset emissions, do I buy all 25 tonnes in one year for $10,000, or do I need to buy 1 tonne for $400 and find the rest elsewhere? Or can I do either, as a tonne is a tonne?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! We have a related question here https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1242/99.
Do the answers there help you, or do you feel your question is rather different?